# Typescript: define function, which transforms an object, keeping keys

Tags: typescript

I need to define a function, which accepts an object of this type:

```
interface Source<A> {
    [index: string]: A
}
```

and transforms that object, **keeping the keys**, but replaces a values:

```
interface Target<B> {
    [index: string]: B
}
```

and I also want to keep typechecking for that case. This is example:

```
function transform(source) {
    var result = {}
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        result[key] = source[key] + "prefix"
    })
}

var target = transform({
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
})

// now target has a {"key1": "1prefix", "key2": "2prefix"}

var three = target.key3 // I want to get type error here on compile-time
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible with the `keyof` keyword.

```
type Mock<K, T> = {
    [P in keyof K]: T
}
```

This will create a type which has all of the properties of type `K`, but the value type of those properties will be `T`.

You could then modify your function to return `Mock<A, B>` and the compiler would enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are after here. You can do something like this:

```
interface Source<U> {
    [index: string]: U
}

var transform =  <U>(source: Source<U>) : Source<string> => {
    var result: Source<string> = {}
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        result[key] = source[key] + "prefix"
    })

    return result;
}

var target = transform({ "key1": 1, "key2": 2 });

// will give error "Type 'string' is not assignable to 'number'"
var blah: number = target["key1"];

// will work (compile and run)..
var blah2: string = target["key1"];

// will compile but crash at run time
var blah2: string = target["random string"];

// will not compile 'Property 'key1' does not  exist on type 'Source<string>'
var blah2: string = target.key1;
```

The last case will never compile. Typescript runs all type checking att compile time. And there is no way for typescript to know that there exists a `target['key1']` property. There is no way to get that to work, if that is what you want.

Comment: No, this is not the solution. I do not want runtime errors on target["random string"]

Comment: As I suspected then, that is in no way possible.

Answer (score 0):

The type information you add to a function should match up to the contract it promises to fulfil. In your original example (adjusted here to return the `result` object) you take in a `source` of `any` type.

```
function transform(source) {
    var result = {}

    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        result[key] = source[key] + "suffix";
    });

    return result;
}
```

If you want tight type checking, you would need to make things more explicit:

```
interface A {
    key1: number;
    key2: number;
}

interface B {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
}

function transformAtoB(a: A) : B {
    return <B>transform(a);
}
```

In the above example, because you know that the input type `A` has properties named `key1` and `key2` you can promise to return an object with the same property names (but different types).

You could reduce the number of interfaces by making one generic interface:

```
interface A<T> {
    key1: T;
    key2: T;
}

function transformAtoB(a: A<number>) : A<string> {
    return <A<string>>transform(a);
}
```

The outcome is that you have full type information, which will catch the below mistake:

```
var target = transformAtoB({
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
});

console.log(target.key1);
console.log(target.key2);
console.log(target.key3); // Compiler warning
```